# Instantiate a contract using interface generated by TypeChain

Tags: ethers.js, typescript, typechain

in my solidity codebase I am using an interface and these are the types generated by TypeChain:

```
import { BaseContract, BigNumber, BigNumberish, BytesLike, CallOverrides, PopulatedTransaction, Signer, utils } from "ethers";
import { FunctionFragment, Result } from "@ethersproject/abi";
import { Listener, Provider } from "@ethersproject/providers";
import { TypedEventFilter, TypedEvent, TypedListener, OnEvent } from "./common";

export interface IHintHelpersInterface extends utils.Interface {
    contractName: "IHintHelpers";
    functions: {
        "getApproxHint(uint256,uint256,uint256)": FunctionFragment;
    };
    encodeFunctionData(functionFragment: "getApproxHint", values: [BigNumberish, BigNumberish, BigNumberish]): string;
    decodeFunctionResult(functionFragment: "getApproxHint", data: BytesLike): Result;
    events: {};
}

export interface IHintHelpers extends BaseContract {
    contractName: "IHintHelpers";
    connect(signerOrProvider: Signer | Provider | string): this;
    attach(addressOrName: string): this;
    deployed(): Promise<this>;
    interface: IHintHelpersInterface;
    queryFilter<TEvent extends TypedEvent>(event: TypedEventFilter<TEvent>, fromBlockOrBlockhash?: string | number | undefined, toBlock?: string | number | undefined): Promise<Array<TEvent>>;
    listeners<TEvent extends TypedEvent>(eventFilter?: TypedEventFilter<TEvent>): Array<TypedListener<TEvent>>;
    listeners(eventName?: string): Array<Listener>;
    removeAllListeners<TEvent extends TypedEvent>(eventFilter: TypedEventFilter<TEvent>): this;
    removeAllListeners(eventName?: string): this;
    off: OnEvent<this>;
    on: OnEvent<this>;
    once: OnEvent<this>;
    removeListener: OnEvent<this>;
    functions: {
        getApproxHint(_CR: BigNumberish, _numTrials: BigNumberish, _inputRandomSeed: BigNumberish, overrides?: CallOverrides): Promise<[
            string,
            BigNumber,
            BigNumber
        ] & {
            hintAddress: string;
            diff: BigNumber;
            latestRandomSeed: BigNumber;
        }>;
    };
    getApproxHint(_CR: BigNumberish, _numTrials: BigNumberish, _inputRandomSeed: BigNumberish, overrides?: CallOverrides): Promise<[
        string,
        BigNumber,
        BigNumber
    ] & {
        hintAddress: string;
        diff: BigNumber;
        latestRandomSeed: BigNumber;
    }>;
    callStatic: {
        getApproxHint(_CR: BigNumberish, _numTrials: BigNumberish, _inputRandomSeed: BigNumberish, overrides?: CallOverrides): Promise<[
            string,
            BigNumber,
            BigNumber
        ] & {
            hintAddress: string;
            diff: BigNumber;
            latestRandomSeed: BigNumber;
        }>;
    };
    filters: {};
    estimateGas: {
        getApproxHint(_CR: BigNumberish, _numTrials: BigNumberish, _inputRandomSeed: BigNumberish, overrides?: CallOverrides): Promise<BigNumber>;
    };
    populateTransaction: {
        getApproxHint(_CR: BigNumberish, _numTrials: BigNumberish, _inputRandomSeed: BigNumberish, overrides?: CallOverrides): Promise<PopulatedTransaction>;
    };
}
//# sourceMappingURL=IHintHelpers.d.ts.map
```

How would I use this to instantiate a contract using Typescript and ethers? Do I simply have to create a class implementing this interface?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about this:

Method 1: (not using generated factory)

```typescript
import { IHintHelpers } from '../typechain-types'; 

const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer) as IHintHelpers;
```

Method 2: (using the generated factory in typechain)

```typescript
import { IHintHelpers__factory } from '../typechain-types'; 

const contract = IHintHelpers__factory.connect(address, signer);
```

Comment: Method 2 worked great. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Define the type as both BaseContract and the typechain type:

```js
import { Contract, BaseContract } from 'ethers'
import { IHintHelpers } from '../typechain-types'; 

const contract = new Contract(address, abi, signer) as BaseContract as IHintHelpers;
```