How to get proper typesafe version from ethers.getContractAt or any other alternative method
I have a hardhat + typescript project , where I have a script like the below:
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { diamond as diamondAddress } from "../../deploy/addresses.json";

async function main() {

    const diamondLoupeFacet = await ethers.getContractAt("DiamondLoupeFacet", diamondAddress)

    const facetAddresses = await diamondLoupeFacet.facetAddresses();
    console.log(`facetAddresses: ${JSON.stringify(facetAddresses, null, 2)}`)

    const facets = await diamondLoupeFacet.facets();
    console.log(`facets: ${JSON.stringify(facets, null, 2)}`)
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });

in this line  const diamondLoupeFacet = await ethers.getContractAt("DiamondLoupeFacet", diamondAddress), the type for diamondLoupeFacet is Contract, but I want to get the proper type , ie, DiamondLoupeFacet that is already generated via typechain.
Is it possible? can it be done?

Found an answer here:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/154603/22522
basically, we need to do
const diamondLoupeFacet = (await ethers.getContractAt("DiamondLoupeFacet", diamondAddress)) as BaseContract as TDiamondLoupeFacet
full code:
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { BaseContract } from "ethers";
import { diamond as diamondAddress } from "../../deploy/addresses.json";
import { DiamondLoupeFacet as TDiamondLoupeFacet } from "../../typechain-types/facets/DiamondLoupeFacet";

async function main() {

    const diamondLoupeFacet = (await ethers.getContractAt("DiamondLoupeFacet", diamondAddress)) as BaseContract as TDiamondLoupeFacet

    const facetAddresses = await diamondLoupeFacet.facetAddresses();
    console.log(`facetAddresses: ${JSON.stringify(facetAddresses, null, 2)}`)

    const facets = await diamondLoupeFacet.facets();
    console.log(`facets: ${JSON.stringify(facets, null, 2)}`)
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });

This works!
